# Как эффективно найти подстроку с маской в строке

Tags: python-3.x

Есть некое подобие пути к какому-то объекту:

> /folder40053/fileparent4413/file/

и  подобных "folder40053" может быть много. Как используя регулярные выражения на питоне эффективнее обрабатывать запросы для поиска типа

> /folder4*/fileparent*/file

что бы получать то, что находиться по пути в запросе, при этом учитывать с какой стороны стоит звёздочка?

Comment: У вас есть список строк и из них нужно отобрать какие-то по шаблону, например регуляркой?

Comment: да, проблема заключается в том, что на вход мы точно получаем выражение типа "word*", и в зависимости от местонахождения той самой звёздочки искать совпадение.

Comment: Выражение `/folder4*/fileparent*/file` на регулярках было бы таким: `/folder4.*/fileparent.*/file`

Comment: пробегать по строке и подменять звёздочки точками выглядит немного как костыль, мне кажется

Comment: Ну, вы говорили про регулярки. Я вам дал пример регулярки. А то, что у вас в вопросе, это wildcard: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fnmatch.html